# Set key with value on a line in a file, if not exists between specific lines, or set specific value

Tags: bash, scripting, qt5

Given the following configuration file:

```
    shape {
        visible: true
        type: rectangle
        ...
    }
    
    shape {
        type: circle
        visible: isRound === "true"
        ...
    }
    
    shape {
        // comment: "visible" not set, default "true" 
    }
```

How to set using `bash` all the values for `visible` key (property) to `false`, without touching the comments, but keeping the old value as a comment?
The new content should be:

```
    shape {
        visible: false
        type: rectangle
        ...
    }
    
    shape {
        type: circle
        visible: false // visible: isRound === "true"
        // ideally, above, the old value is kept as a comment...
        ...
    }
    
    shape {
        visible: false
        // comment: "visible" not set, default "true" 
    }
```

The file is not just a list of `shape` structures, may contain other entries too. This should be **QML** compliant.

`awk` shows:

```
awk --version
GNU Awk 5.2.1, API 3.2
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2022 Free Software Foundation.
```

**Edit**

I think I can use this `PCRE regex`:

```
(\s*shape\s*\{\n)(\s*)(.*?)(visible\:.*\n?)?(.*?)(\n\s*\})
```

with replace expression as:

```
$1$2visible: false // $4\n$2$5$6
```

or

```
\1\2visible: false // \4\n\2\5\6
```

but I need a tool to apply it. It is not perfect, still needs to not comment twice.

Comment: Please, add expected output

Comment: And tell us if you need to not replace what is in comments `//` and `/*  */`

Comment: It would have been interesting to have the example output since the beginning =)

Comment: Well, I try to put it simple. My apologies if I have mislead.

Comment: You should specify which kind of language is it, looks like `CSS`. If then, add the proper tag by editing your post.

Comment: You say that tho output should be valid QML.  Given that the _input_ is not valid QML, are you expecting an answer that _corrects_ the given file?  If the input is valid QML, have you attempted to use the `qml` utility in Qt5 to do these modifications?

Comment: It is a snapshot of it, indeed those would be contained in an `Container {}` construct, I do not intend to develop something, just set some values as OS admin at some point.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `perl` for this kind of thing:

```
perl -0777 -pe '
  s{shape\s*\{.*?\}}{
    $& =~ s{(//.*)|\b(visible:\s*+)(?!true\s*$).*}{$1 ? $1 : "${2}true // $&"}gmre
  }gse' your-file
```

Comment: I can't use perl.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v key='visible:' -v value='false' '
    /{/ {
        found=0 # reset flag
    }
    $1==key {
        found=1 # set flag
        
        # change true to value
        if ($2=="true") { sub($2, value, $0) }

        # if not value, replace property with key-value and comment
        else if ($2!=value) { sub($1, $1 " " value " // " $1, $0) }
    }
    /}/ && !found {
        # get indentation of }
        indent=$0; sub(/}.*/, "", indent)
        
        # insert property
        print indent indent key " " value
    }
    { print }
' file
```

There must not be any other opening `{` or closing `}` in your properties/comments or the insertion won't work. They must also occur on separate lines.

A missing property is inserted before the closing `}` and the indentation
is set to two times the indentation of `}`. I'm not sure if this will be always correct or how to determine it (two tabs?).

If a property already has the right value, it is left untouched.

If you don't want to repeat the property name in comments, change the command to `sub($1, $1 " " value " //", $0)`.
The result would be `visible: false // isRound === "true"`.

Output:

```
    shape {
        visible: false
        type: rectangle
        ...
    }
    
    shape {
        type: circle
        visible: false // visible: isRound === "true"
        ...
    }
    
    shape {
        // comment: "visible" not set, default "true" 
        visible: false
    }
```

Comment: Consider this inline CSS example: `div .class{ property: 1; visible: false }` it will fails

Comment: I don't know what kind of "configuration file" this is, but it's not CSS (no `;` and `//` comments are not allowed). I only fear the config is nested.

Comment: This code is absolutely valid `CSS`. See https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_howto.asp And `//` and `;` are allowed for sure

Comment: @GillesQuénot OPs "configuration file" has no semicolons, it would be broken CSS. And `//`-style comments are not allowed in CSS (see [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments), or [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#comment-diagram)).

Comment: So OP CSS and what you edit with `awk` is broken so(?). There's `//` both in answer and question

Comment: @GillesQuénot Again, I don't know what kind of input that is. Ask OP.

Comment: Think the syntax is QML.

Comment: The above works to add in any section, regardless it is `shape` or not.